# Error al ejecutar Sonarqube con Jenkins

Tags: git, gitlab, jenkins, sonar

Estoy tratando de analizar mi proyecto con **Sonarqube** en **Jenkins**, sin embargo siempre que voy a construir mi proyecto me sale un error mas exactamente el siguiente:

```
Lanzada por el usuario
Ejecutando.en el espacio de trabajo C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\IngenieriaIII
 > C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe config remote.origin.url # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from https://gitlab.com/sebastianslz/IngenieriaIII.git
 > C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe --version # timeout=10
using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials 
 > C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe fetch --tags --progress https://gitlab.com/sebastianslz/IngenieriaIII.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
 > C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe rev-parse "refs/remotes/origin/branch^{commit}" # timeout=10
 > C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe rev-parse "refs/remotes/origin/origin/branch^{commit}" # timeout=10
Checking out Revision c02f544383ce78c649e18426f3693805d2a01657 (refs/remotes/origin/branch)
 > C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe checkout -f c02f544383ce78c649e18426f3693805d2a01657
Commit message: "Se agrego el archivo  build.xml"
 > C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe rev-list --no-walk c02f544383ce78c649e18426f3693805d2a01657 # timeout=10
[IngenieriaIII] $ "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\tools\hudson.plugins.sonar.SonarRunnerInstallation\Scanner_3.0.3\bin\sonar-scanner.bat" -Dsonar.host.url=htto://localhost:9000 ******** -Dsonar.language=php -Dsonar.projectName=IngenieriaIII -Dsonar.projectVersion=1 -Dsonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8 "-Dsonar.projectDescription=Proyecto de Ingenieria III" -Dsonar.projectKey=IngenieriaIII -Dsonar.sources=. "-Dsonar.projectBaseDir=C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\IngenieriaIII"
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/sonarsource/scanner/cli/Main : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)
Exception in thread "main" WARN: Unable to locate 'report-task.txt' in the workspace. Did the SonarScanner succedeed?
ERROR: SonarQube scanner exited with non-zero code: 1
Finished: FAILURE
```

Este es mi archivo Analysis properties

```
#*****************************************************
# Project Identification
#*****************************************************
sonar.projectKey=ProjectKey
sonar.projectName=ProjectName
sonar.projectVersion=1
sonar.projectDescription=DescriptionName
#*****************************************************
#*****************************************************
sonar.sources=.
sonar.language=php
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
#*****************************************************
```

Y esta es la ubicacion de mi proyecto

[image: Localizacion del proyecto]

Mi version de **Sonarqube** es 5.6.7
Version de **Jenkins** es 2.107.2

Ahora realmente no entiendo cómo funciona esto y cómo debo configurarlo, no entiendo cómo funciona esto exactamente

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es un problema del runtime de Java que estás usando. Revisa que version de java estás lanzando.

- Java SE 10 = 54
- Java SE 9 = 53
- Java SE 8 = 52
- Java SE 7 = 51

....
Posiblemente estás intentando ejecutar el análisis sonar con java7 o inferior. Cambia al Jre 8 o superior.